# Restoring deleted designators on Altium PCB

Tags: pcb, altium, layout, assembly

Is there a way to restore component designators on the PCB without having to delete and re-add the component in the schematic? I deleted quite a few designators while I was laying out the design and now they're not showing up on the Assembly drawing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How did you manage to delete your designators? If I try to delete them in my installation of AD17 nothing happens. Did you delete them in the library?

If you somehow managed to delete them on the PCB design simply go to Tools --> Update From PCB Libraries. Select all layers, click 'OK", and in the next dialog click "Update All" and "Accept Changes (Create ECO)". This will update all of the components on your board to match what's in the libraries, which should include designators.

I still don't see how you managed to delete the designators to begin with though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you removed the designators, and what version of Altium you are using, this can be a fix:

Open the PCB List panel, set it to Edit all objects, Include only Components, and scroll to the right. There is a Column callled "show name". Tick the box corresponding to the component you want to see the designator for, and it should come back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Altium 17.1, and I think the issue is I didn't just hide the designators, I clicked on them and deleted them. I've resorted to just manually placing strings on them and they are successfully showing up in the Assembly drawing now. It's slow but it seems to be working.

Comment: I am not sure about Altium, but can you refresh or update footprints?